# Resturing data using Firebaselistobservable Nesting

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nested, angularfire

Below is the structure of my classes inside firebase:

```
{

  "groups" : {
    "-KjkdYVP3N69GaDfLwS1" : {
      "groupname" : "Ballet Class",
      "description" : "8 years onwards",
      "picture" : "assets/img/dance.jpg",
      "type" : "dance"
    },
    "-KjkdYVP3N69GaDfLwS2" : {
      "groupname" : "Ballet Class",
      "description" : "8 years onwards",
      "picture" : "assets/img/dance.jpg",
      "type" : "dance"
    },
    "-KjkdYVP3N69GaDfLwS3" : {
      "groupname" : "Ballet Class",
      "description" : "8 years onwards",
      "picture" : "assets/img/dance.jpg",
      "type" : "dance"
    },
    "-KjkdYVP3N69GaDfLwS4" : {
      "groupname" : "Ballet Class",
      "description" : "8 years onwards",
      "picture" : "assets/img/dance.jpg",
      "type" : "dance"
    }
  },

  "linking" : {
    "DCuf5MvTlpQa0LC4BoJWedIiFfc2" : {
      "groupid" : {
        "-KjkdYVP3N69GaDfLwS1" : true,
        "-KjkdYVP3N69GaDfLwS2" : true,
        "-KjkdYVP3N69GaDfLwS3" : true,
        "-KjkdYVP3N69GaDfLwS4" : true
      },
      "memberid" : {
        "-KjkdduprKpr8e0P7KH1" : true,
        "-KjkdduprKpr8e0P7KH2" : true,
        "-KjkdduprKpr8e0P7KH3" : true,
        "-KjkdduprKpr8e0P7KH4" : true

      },
      "role" : "admin",
      "uid" : "DCuf5MvTlpQa0LC4BoJWedIiFfc2"
    }
  },
}
```

I have 2 classes 'linking' and 'groups'. Once user logs in, I want to fetch the details of the user groups from the linking table and further want to fetch group details on the basis of group id's return by first query. I write both of these queries independently:

Fetching groups from linking class:-
this.groupid = this.af.database.list('/linking/'+uid +'groupid);

Fetching details of the groups:
this.groupdetails = this.af.database.list('/groups'+this.groupid);

But I know this code is not valid.

Can someone please suggest the right way to handle this requirement?

I ultimately want to display group details on a page

```
<li  *ngFor="let group of groups| async">
               {{ (group.data | async)?.field }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var groups = [];
this.af.database.object('linking/'+ uid).subscribe(linking=>{
linking.groupid.forEach(groupid=>{
 groups.push(this.af.database.list('/groups'+groupid));
})
})
```

This should give you an idea how to retrieve your data. cheers :)